# In Django, how do I join a table with a composite primary key to another table?

Tags: python, django, left-join, composite-primary-key

Here's what I have in the way of models:

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='leads')
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    ...

class UserDemographic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_demographic')
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = 'user', 'site'
```

In the first model, we record leads on a per-site, per-user basis.   There can be multiple leads from the same user on a given site.  In the second model, we store each user's demographic data.  For each site, each use has only one record of demographic data.

What I would like to be able to do is tack this demographic data onto our leads query.   Each lead has both user and site, and I want to grab the data in the demographic table and pair it to the corresponding lead. So basically what I need here is a left join that will unite these two.  This is simple enough to do when there is only one foreign key, but I have no clue how to make it work when there are two foreign keys on which to join the tables.

Any ideas on this? Is there even a way to do this in Django, or will I have to resort to a raw query?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's ORM doesn't let you do this natively, but you can minimise your raw sql by using the [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method. Something like this should work:

```
Lead.objects.extra(tables=['appname_userdemographic'], 
                   where=['appname_userdemographic.user_id=appname_lead.user_id',
                          'appname_userdemographic.site_id=appname_lead.site_id'],
                   select={'country': 'appname_userdemographic.country'})
```

Alternately, you could refactor your models so you don't need the composite key - for example, create a UserSite model and link your lead and demographic models to that.

```
class UserSite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)

class Lead(models.Model):
    user_site = models.OneToOneField(UserSite)
    ...

class UserDemographic(models.Model):
    user_site = models.OneToOneField(UserSite)
    ...
```

Then you can use select_related, like so:

```
Lead.objects.select_related('usersite__userdemographic')
```

Comment: Hm.  That is kinda surprising they don't have something built-in.  Seems like a fairly common thing to have to do.  Was curious about your UserSite suggestion, and I'm not quite sure what you have in mind.  Think you could give a short example?

Comment: Also, tried out your suggestion above.  It works to return everything okay when there is data in UserDemographic, but when there isn't, no results.  So this is effectively an inner join.  Is there a way to do a left join with extra?

Comment: Ok, sorry I think you're out of luck then - the Django core devs have stubbornly refused to add any custom left join capability to the ORM: see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7231 . I'll update my answer with some more details.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So basically UserSite becomes an intermediate model that effectively ties together User and Site foreign keys into a composite key by giving each unique combination of user and site an id of its own.  Then we can move back and forth between models that use UserSite to relate data.  Very clever!